# How to make a view move on touch along a predefined path ? (45 degree angle)

Tags: java, android, animation

Would like to (on press) drag and move a view object(circle) along a predefined path. Looking thru the MotionEvent library on android currently
[image]
Please see the link attached

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/functionsandgraphs/p(t)%3D(t%2B1%2C+2t-3).gif

[animation](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/functionsandgraphs/p(t)%3D(t%2B1%2C+2t-3).gif)